# SQL-based Event Management - How can users be registered to event?

Tags: sql, user-management

I'd like to create an event management system. Events are stored in one SQL database, Users in another SQL database. 
Users are supposed to be able to register to as many events as they like. I'm having trouble modelling this in SQL.
Could somebody point me in the right direction of how to realize this functionality?
Seems to me this should be easy to accomplish but I'm missing out on something.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bit broad. Do you need to know how to set up a many-to-many relationship by using an associative table? you can find a lot of material on this issue. Or do you need to know how to set up an application or integrate the 2 databases?

Comment: I just figured it out. I was actually stuck at how to modle the tables because in my mind there were only two: Users and Events. I wondered if I have to store all events a users attends row-wise in the Users-table. Adding a third table didn't even cross my mind. Obviously the solution is to create a third table with User_ID and Event_ID as foreign keys. Many thanks for your answer :).

Comment: Well... enforcing the foreign key across tables that reside in different databases may not be that easy (depends on DBRMS I suppose), but at least you would have a correct structure.